# Howto easily create a diagram using firebug loading and/or executing times?

Tags: performance, firebug, diagram, pie-chart

I need to create diagram showing the most time consuming tasks when a specific page gets loaded.
Well, Firebug has this nice feature to show you all loading times of files in the network section or if i can use the profiler alternatively (console).

Now i am looking for the easiest way to get a diagram (pie chart) from the results without typing all the files and time values into an excell table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export as a Har file ([extension to allow firebug Har log file export](http://getfirebug.com/releases/netexport/)), this HarViewer looks promising...

https://github.com/janodvarko/harviewer

HAR Viewer is a web application (PHP + Javascript) that allows to visualize HTTP tracing logs based on HTTP Archive format (HAR). These files contain recorded information about HTTP traffic performed by web pages.

[image]

---Also---

http://www.imagossoftware.com/harlog/

HarLog takes HAR format files or a HAR HTTP formatted stream and creates a tab delimited output file. The output file can then be imported into Excel or similar to create graphical reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a chart using the Google Chart API: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/chart/ directly in the browser. (no excell needed ;-) )